# Save custom attribute in user database instead of userpool

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I'm setting up an endpoint to save custom attribute on the user in the database instead of Cognito pool. The reason why I am doing this is, the restriction of the congnito pool to modify the attributes and it is very much limited to only 25 attributes. 
The problem is, I have an invite link which comes from a registered user with his `referralId`. When the link is clicked, it renders sign-up page asking non-registered user to sign up. When he signs up and if `Auth.signup` promise is resolved, then he is redirected to thank you page asking him to confirm the email address before logging in. At this point in time, I can actually extract `referralId` from the query param `(http://localhost:3000/invite?referralId={id})`.

I am confused at this stage, how I can define my serverless endpoint because the `signInSession` comes as undefined since the user is not yet confirmed! If user goes into his email and verifies the email, there is no way I can fetch the `referralId` at this stage because it was set in `MessageCustomizations` of Cognito pool.

I have tried the following code to set up the serverless endpoint

Since I am using reactjs in the front end, this is how I have `post` requested the `referrerId`.

```
import HttpClient from './httpClient';

class UserCustomAttributesController extends HttpClient {
  saveReferrerId = async (referrerId) => {
    const response = await this.client.post(`/invite?referredId=${referrerId}`);
    return response.data;
  };
}

export default new UserCustomAttributesController();
```

In the backend though,

```
    handler: lib/functions/updateUser/index.handler
    events: 
      - http: 
          path: /invite
          method: put
          request: 
            template: 
              application/json: '{ "referrerId" : "$input.params(''referrerId'')" }' 
          cors: 
            origin: "*"
            headers: 
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              # - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer: 
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer
```

I want to save the referrerId on to the user in the database. I have no lead since I am just beginning up learning serverless and aws.

Comment: How about customize your email verification message in Amazon Cognito? can you include your referrerId there?

Comment: Hi Luillyfe, my application flow goes as the following:-

Comment: 1) Succesfully signed up user sends the invite link to non-registered user's email                                                     2) Non-registered user clicks on invite link(https://mywebsite/invite?referrerId={id}) and the url renders sign up component just as signup page                3) When non-registered user signs up, he is sent with a confirmation email which was defined in AWS console and he is redirected to thank you page asking him to confirm his email so that he can log in to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a Cognito post-confirmation trigger (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html). This should allow you to save the data to a DB with all user information once they have confirmed their email.

Another approach would just be to save all the information with a field such as `isEmailConfirmed` which can then be changed to `true` once the person has verified their email.